# Swift fat framework w/Objective-C Cocoapod

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I've built a framework in Swift. The framework uses Cocoapods, one of the pods is written in Objective C.

I also use a custom script to make the framework a fat framework so it supports 32/64 bit systems. (This runs in a separate target on the project and I'm wondering if that has something to do with it?)

```
UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-universal

if [ "true" == ${ALREADYINVOKED:-false} ]
then
echo "RECURSION: Detected, stopping"
else
export ALREADYINVOKED="true"

// Step 1. Build Device and Simulator versions
xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos  BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}"   BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build
xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build

//Step 2. Copy the framework structure (from iphoneos build) to the universal folder
cp -R "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/"

// Step 3. Copy Swift modules (from iphonesimulator build) to the copied framework directory
cp -R "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/Modules/${PROJECT_NAME}.swiftmodule/." "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/Modules/${PROJECT_NAME}.swiftmodule"

// Step 4. Create universal binary file using lipo and place the combined executable in the copied framework directory
lipo -create -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}"

// Step 5. Convenience step to copy the framework to the project's directory
cp -R "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework" "${PROJECT_DIR}"

// Step 6. Convenience step to open the project's directory in Finder
open "${PROJECT_DIR}"

fi
```

When I create this fat framework and put it into a project I'd like to use it on the compiler always fails b/c the project can't see the objective C cocoa pod module.

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ld: framework not found Pusher for architecture x86_64
```

It is not found for any architecture when I change the build platform.

Any solution where I can produce a framework that I can use in a separate Xcode project (for all iOS or OS X) would be awesome.

Answer (score 7):

You can't run `xcodebuild` with `-target` when using CocoaPods.  When you use `-target`, Xcode will only consider the active project and fail to pull in the Pod dependencies, similar to if you just opened the project file in Xcode and tried building.

You should be running `xcodebuild -workspace "${PROJECT_NAME}.xcworkspace" -scheme "${PROJECT_NAME}" ...`, assuming that CocoaPods generated the workspace and Xcode generated a scheme using the target name.  You will also need to make sure your scheme is marked as shared if running this on another device.

Once your framework is built you will need to include it **and the frameworks it depends on** in apps that will be using it.  For your framework, that means including it in General > Embedded Binaries and General > Linked Frameworks and Libraries.  For frameworks you depend on, (e.g. AlamoFire), you could instruct users to include it in their Podfile, you could package it and ship it along with your framework, or you could do both and let the user do what works for them.

Comment: Would there be anything else that I need to do or change? I don't get a compiler error about it not finding a module but when I try to run anything I get: ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/74636985-3538-4693-B131-983106003055/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/FBC92D11-240D-45BB-9F21-C4372DE509B4/TestMyKit.app/TestMyKit
  Reason: image not found
(lldb)

Comment: Is that the full error? No info on what image it couldn't load? Is the .framework listed in both libraries to link and binaries to embed for that app?

Comment: This is the full error:dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
  Referenced from: ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/74636985-3538-4693-B131-983106003055/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/FFC6E8DA-4877-4142-A97B-73A3B7712319/TestMyKit.app/Frameworks/DICAPIKit.framework/DICAPIKit
  Reason: image not found
(lldb) - Yes the framework is both linked and embedded.

Comment: Since your framework references Alamofire.framework, your app also needs to embed it. Your app should include Alamofire in its podfile and you should build your app from the workspace, not project. Same goes for any other dependencies of the framework.

Comment: Ah ha, my question is a bit inaccurate then - I just never got to the point when that would fail then. Is there no way to compile Alamofire into my framework to make it a bit more modular - esp. using it with a repo.

Comment: That may be possible with ObjC, not sure about Swift dependencies like Alamofire. The problem you'd have then is that any project trying to use both your library and Alamofire would get linker warnings (errors?) about duplicate definitions of objects. You could consider copying the Alamofire source into your project so you'd have your own namespaced version, dropping the dependency entirely and using NSURLSession directly, or giving your customers a compiled Alamofire.framework along with your framework.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are missing the 64bit architecture for Simulator.

When you build a target from Xcode, depending on what kind of simulator you have selected - the produced library will contains i386 or x86_64 respectively for selected 32bit or 64bit version of the simulator.

I guess that the cli build is producing only i386 version.

You can try to set the architectures in the script:

`xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" ARCHS="i386 x86_64" -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build`

As an alternative You can try to build by hand using 64bit simulator (iPhone 5S +), then extract the missing architecture and then put it into the final library using lipo command.

Comment: I believe that's taken care of by the ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO args. Aside from that it also works when there isn't an Objective-C cocoa pod.